# Negative and positive voltage from a single 12 V battery

Tags: batteries, 5v, motherboard, negative-voltage

I am trying to power my CPU with a single 12 V battery.

For 12 V, 5 V, and 3.3 V I have decided to use a buck converter using a 555, but I can't find any solution to get -5 V and -12 V out of that same battery.

I have tried using a 7905 for -5 V, but it's heating a lot (maybe because it's connected wrong; GND is connected to +ve and Vin is connected to -ve).

Comment: While what you're trying to achieve is not impossible it's a lot more difficult than just using a 7905 and expecting the output to be negative. At a minimum at least say what sort of current you need on each voltage rail and what kind of battery it is.

Comment: Depending on your CPU (motherboard?) there's a good chance that it does not use the negative voltages at all. You could google the type number and check the documentation.

Comment: Hey PeterJ....i need 0.5A on both...-12v and -5v...

Comment: And thanks Wouter Van Ooijen.....i have a check on it....and i need ur help too.....my MB is M5A88-m Asus.....n cpu is Phenom X4 970....

Comment: There are plenty of computer power supplies that take 12VDC input commerically available. It really doesn't sound like you have the knowledge required to save time and/or money by designing your own, not to mention the risk of damamging your computer if you make a mistake.

Comment: Thanks...i will have a look at it....but i wanted to design one.....

Comment: A 79XX needs negative *input*! It does not produce negative output from positive input. It only regulates.

Comment: Use another battery in addition to get the negative voltages.

Comment: You can buy tiny 12v-to-ATX power supplies as used by the Mini-ITX / InCarPC crowd, much easier than trying to roll your own.

Comment: thats true.....but i cant find 500Watt one.....i need atleast 450Watt....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a battery v volts, means by convention that the positive pin is at +v volts and the negative pin is at 0 volts. 
Lets say I need -12 volts, that would mean I need a battery of 24 volts (in the number space there are 24 numbers from -12 to +12. also 12 - (-12) = 24) 
The voltage regulator would give you +5 volts and ground (i.e 5-0 = 5).

[image: convert 12 volts to -5v]

See if this helps. 
You could also see http://www.geofex.com/circuits/+9_to_-9.htm (charge pumps)

I have never done anything like this. Could you please tell me why you are needing a -5v. Is it needed for RS232?
Tell me how it goes.

I don't know if I have correctly in understood your question..
Please reply...

Comment: SO...cxan u give me schematic of wiring up a 7905 to a 12v battery to get -5v....plz... and suppose i have a 24v battery..how will i need to wire up a 7912....

Answer (score -1):

Very old, I know. But technically, the actual answer to this question is: you have to center tap your battery. Which is physically very difficult on most batteries unless the cell connectors are exposed (example = large forklift batteries). The question states "CPU" which obviously means "Motherboard". Therefore, for positive 12 Volts AND negative 12 Volts, produced from a "single" integrated power source, you need to connect two 12 Volt batteries in series, which creates the "center tap" connection. Then you connect your positive 12 Volts output to the positive end of the battery combo, the Ground output where the two batteries are connected to each other in series, and the negative 12 Volts output to the negative end of the battery combo. Done. (No regulators needed obviously). HOWEVER, the voltage from this power source will drop faster after some number of hours depending on battery chemistry. So this power source can only operate output loads that can handle under-voltage, such as motors or something else that can go slower -- or dimmer -- so, using this to power semiconductors will NOT work unless you are doing something that only takes minutes before needing new batteries or recharging. So the overall solution to this situation is to connect batteries with voltages higher than the rated output voltages, but not with voltages that exceed the Voltage Regulators max input. So, for +/- 12 Volts output, you can use four(4) 12 Volt batteries in series, center tap in the very center of the battery combo, and make sure your voltage regulators can handle 24 volts input using the correct current flow direction (reversed voltage input or not reversed voltage input). There should be NO out of tolerance need for regulator input filter capacitors on this circuit. But the two regulator outputs may need capacitor filters to reduce any out of tolerance regulator charge switching. Which when powering computer logic circuits, we really need to reduce any voltage variations as much as possible = put caps on the regulator outputs. IT IS ALSO PHYSICALLY POSSIBLE to connect the four batteries in a parallel/series, or a total parallel configuration, which would give an increase in battery life before voltage drop, but this is possibly not a good solution because the highest voltage battery will cause current flow into lower voltage batteries which probably decreases current flow in the overall power supply output. The good thing about using 4 batteries is the increase in overall Amp/Hour rating versus using only 2 batteries. In other words, four batteries in series will last longer than 2 batteries in series connected to the same load.

Comment: To increase deflection: motherboards need storage most existing hard drives need 12 volts

Comment: Don't add "addenda" in the comments, [edit] your answer and place them there. Also, your answer could do with some spacing and breaking up into paragraphs - as it stands, it is a wall of text, that isn't particularly easy to read.